# How can I model a "Select, Map, Save to local file" report in ABAP OO?

Tags: abap

The Report is required to select master data based on Selection-Screen input, map the needed fields into new export structure, transform to XML and save to local file.

Since there are multiple Reports doing to this for different types of master data I started by creating an abstract class in which I put the elements useful for all Reports and intend to create one class for each report inheriting from that class.

I then call a static method from the report which creates the instance of the report class and starts the process.

```
REPORT ztesten.

PARAMETERS p1 TYPE c.
PARAMETERS p2 TYPE c.

START-OF-SELECTION.

  zcl_class=>main(
    EXPORTING p1 = p1
              p2 = p2 ). 
METHOD main.
  DATA(lo_class) =
    NEW zcl_tradenet_export_kostl(
        p1 = p1
        p2 = p2 ).
  lo_class->start_process( ).
ENDMETHOD.
```

I am struggling so far with what to use as attributes since it is generally advised to avoid using global data. Currently I store all parameters and other read only data that is selected from the database at the start of the program (this is done to avoid doing selects multiple times in loops) and then needed throughout the report as well as the export structure. If I wanted to avoid that I would have to drag them all along the call stack which seems even more impractical to me even though it uses local and not global data.

For the parameters and DB data this seems somehow ok since the attribute is only read and not changed, but as for the export structure I have more concerns since it is filled progressively. Yet dragging it along seems also impractical since it would bloat method signatures.

How would you deal with those aspects?

One final Question: Using my current approach, the number of attributes can get large fairly quickly if the selection screen has many elements or many database tables are read beforehand. Would you group them in structures to Keep the number down and make things clearer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a class that provides public members to store all your parameters.

```
CLASS ztesten_config DEFINITION PUBLIC CREATE PUBLIC.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    DATA p1 TYPE c.
    DATA p2 TYPE c.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS ztesten_config IMPLEMENTATION.
ENDCLASS.
```

Instantiate the class and store your parameters inside.

```
REPORT ztesten.

PARAMETERS p1 TYPE c.
PARAMETERS p2 TYPE c.

START-OF-SELECTION.
  DATA(config) = NEW ztesten_config( ).
  config->p1 = p1.
  config->p2 = p2.
  zcl_class=>main( config ).
```

You can now pass that object through your call stack. This may still be annoying, but less so because it is only a single parameter. It is also the cleanest solution, because it minimizes state and coupling of your classes.

```
METHOD main.
  DATA(lo_class) = NEW zcl_tradenet_export_kostl( ).
  lo_class->start_process( config ).
ENDMETHOD.
```

If your objects represent process*es* ("bla_calculation"), not process*ors* ("bla_calculator"), you can reduce the number of parameter passes by passing the config to the classes' constructors and letting them save in some private attribute. This requires that you instantiate the classes for each execution of the report anew.

```
METHOD main.
  DATA(lo_class) = NEW zcl_tradenet_calculation( config ).
  lo_class->start_process( ).
ENDMETHOD.
```

You can avoid having to pass the object through the call stack completely by applying patterns like singleton.

```
CLASS ztesten_config DEFINITION PUBLIC CREATE PUBLIC.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    DATA p1 TYPE c.
    DATA p2 TYPE c.
    CLASS-METHODS get_instance
      RETURNING
        VALUE(result) TYPE REF TO ztesten_config.
  PRIVATE SECTION.
    CLASS-DATA singleton TYPE REF TO ztesten_config.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS ztesten_config IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD get_instance.
    IF singleton IS NOT BOUND.
      singleton = NEW #( ).
    ENDIF.
    result = singleton.
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.

METHOD somewhere_inside_tradenet_export_kostl.
  DATA(config) = ztesten_config=>get_instance( ).
  config->p1 [...]
ENDMETHOD.
```

All of these patterns allow you to supply test data instead of the real report input, and to utilize your classes outside of the report context.

For the result of the report, you can follow a similar design, by producing an object that receives and stores the result data piece by piece.

Structuring parameters is always a good idea: it not only makes method signatures smaller, it also adds context which parameters belong together, and how.

Are you familiar with [Clean ABAP](https://github.com/SAP/styleguides/blob/master/clean-abap/CleanABAP.md)? The section [*Aim for few IMPORTING parameters, at best less than three*](https://github.com/SAP/styleguides/blob/master/clean-abap/CleanABAP.md#aim-for-few-importing-parameters-at-best-less-than-three) specifically recommends that "You can reduce the number of parameters by combining them into meaningful sets with structures and objects."

Comment: Hi Florian, thanks for your insights especially on Singleton, it did not occur to me to use it in this context. Could you also comment on structuring members if there is a lot of them (my final question)?

Comment: Sure. Added my thoughts to the end of the post.